# Problems in understanding operations with pointers in C language

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to understand why some characters disappear and after they are 
concatenated in the original string. See, `c = *sibl` receives the first character of `*sibl`,
`*sibl = *inout` receives the content of `*inout` but the character stored in `c` is not more in `*inout`. And, `*inout = c` doesn't change the content of `*inout`, it makes `c` be concatenated to the content of `*inout`.  I don't understand why this happens!

My code:

```
void Cripto (char *inout, int i) {
    char *sibl, c;
    while (*inout) {
        sibl = inout+1;
        if (!sibl)
            break;
        if (*inout >= 'A' && *inout <= 'Z'){
            *inout += i;
        }
        c = *sibl;
        printf("val c %c\n",c);
        printf("val inout after c %s\n",inout);
        printf("val sibl after c %s\n",sibl);
        *sibl = *inout;
        printf("val sibl after att %s\n",sibl);
        *inout = c;
        printf("val inout after att %s\n",inout);
    inout = sibl+1;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[30];
    int i;
    scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
    Cripto(str, i);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
```

}

the outcomes for "teste" 3:

```
val c: e  
val inout after c: teste  
val sibl after c: este  
val sibl after att: tste  
val inout after att: etste  
val c: t  
val inout after c: ste  
val sibl after c: te   
val sibl after att: se  
val inout after att: tse  
val c:  
val inout after c: e  
val sibl after c:    
val sibl after att: e  
val inout after att:
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a specific thing which you don't understand? This program does a lot of things and it isn't clear what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more thing that you need to be cautious (unless you are doing this intentionlly) are the following two lines:

```
sibl = inout+1;
*sibl = *inout;
```

You are pointing sibl to inout + 1 and then assigning the value of sibl (which is essentially a pointer to inout + 1) by the value of inout. This will change the value of inout itself. Thus, if inout is ("123"), then sibl is pointing to "23" and with "*sibl = *inout", you are setting the seccond char of inout (which is sibl) with the first char. Thus, inout would become "113".

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that you're iterating in the `while()` loop in steps of 2:

```
while(*inout) {
    sibl = inout+1;
    // ...
    inout = sibl+1;  // = (inout+1)+1 = inout+2
}
```

What you *seem* to be trying to do is iterate over the string pointed to by `inout` and add `i` (presumably a small value) if `char` is a capital letter, so why not use something like:

```
while(*inout) {
    if( *inout>='A' && *inout<='Z' ) {
        *inout += (char)i;
    }
    inout++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no concatenation going on in this code. There is only overwriting taking place. Here is, what the code does:

1. You have a string in some memory buffer, that serves as input and output. The variable `inout` is a pointer that starts at the beginning of this string. However, as the function progresses, this pointer is modified to point at other characters within this string. Thus, when you later output the string that it points to, only the suffix of the string will be printed. The prefix is still there, but a C string is always interpreted from a start pointer up to a terminating null character.
2. In the first iteration, `inout` is a pointer to the first character, `sibl` is made to point to the second character in the input array. If either one points at the terminating null character, the loop is terminated.
3. If the character that `inout` points to is an upper case, its ASCII value is incremented by i. As a sidenote: This operation is not invertible as it is written, because `'Z' + 3` (or similar) will map to some non-alphanumeric character which itself would not be modified.
4. The sequence `c = *inout; *inout = *sibl; *sibl = c` swaps the two neighbouring characters.
5. `inout = sibl + 1;` effectively moves `inout` forward by two characters since `sibl` was last set to `inout + 1`
6. The second iteration does the same thing to characters 3 and 4 as the first iteration did to characters 1 and two. You don't see the result of the first iteration in your `printf` output anymore, because those two characters are now in front of the two pointers and basically inaccessible within the function. Yet, the pointer in `main` is not modified, and that last `printf` should give you the entire result of the operation.